# Replace lines with a random string ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I want to replace multiple lines in a text file with random strings. This is my code.

```
public static string Random(int ran)
{
        string _allowedChars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        Random randNum = new Random();
        char[] chars = new char[ran];
        int allowedCharCount = _allowedChars.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < ran; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = _allowedChars[(int)((_allowedChars.Length) * randNum.NextDouble())];
        }

        return new string(chars);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string filePath = "try2.txt";
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += 2)
        {
            lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("1", Random(int.Parse("5")));
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);
}
```

But it generates only 1 random string and add it every 2 lines.

[image]

I want to generate different random strings every 2 lines.

I can not figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create `Random randNum` once instead of re-creating it every time.

E.g.

```
static Random randNum = new Random();

public static string Random(int ran)
{
    ....
}
```

If time difference between two

```
Random randNum = new Random();
```

is small, it is likely that the same seed is used.